# ¿Cómo puedo configurar el mensaje y el título de un diálogo desde una actividad?

Tags: android, alertdialog, diálogo

Lo que intento es poder llamar a los métodos
`setTittle()` y `setMessage()` desde alguna actividad, para hacer el diálogo más reutilizable.

```
builder.setMessage("Test dialogo")
            .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                {
                    mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(NoticeDialogFragment.this);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                {
                    mListener.onDialogNegativeClick(NoticeDialogFragment.this);
                }
            });
```

Estoy implementando una interfaz a través de la cual sobreescribo desde la actividad principal los métodos para el `positiveButton` y para el `negativeButton`, y para ejecutar por ejemplo un diálogo hago lo siguiente:

```
 DialogFragment dialogo = new NoticeDialogFragment();
            dialogo.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

¿Alguno sabe cómo puedo hacer esto?

Comment: Si inflas un layout tendrías que agregar un TextView para que a este le puedas setear.. y así considerarlo un título al TextView

Answer (score 0):

El titulo del `DialogFragment` lo puedes cambiar de esta forma:

```
getDialog().setTitle("StackOveflow en español.");
```

por lo tanto si creas una instancia del díalogo, puedes cambiar el titulo de esta instancia:

```
private DialogFragment dialogo;

dialogo = new NoticeDialogFragment();
            dialogo.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");


if (dialogo != null){
   dialogo.setTitle("StackOveflow en español.");
}
```

Comment: Hola ! muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Intenté lo que me dijiste pero no se porque, quizas hice algo mal yo, pero la aplicación se me cerraba. Igualmente pude resolverlo, deje la respuesta por si a alguien le surge la misma duda. Saludos y gracias !

Comment: Si se cerraba es importante revisar el mensaje desplegado en el LogCat, tal vez era otro problema.

Answer (score 0):

antes que nada agradezco las respuestas. Dejo la forma en que lo resolví por si a alguien le surge la misma duda.
En la clase que definí para el dialogo, definí dos atributos (uno para el mensaje y otro para el título del dialogo), junto con sus métodos "set" correspondientes.

```
private String tituloDialogo;
private String mensajeDialogo;
```

Luego en el método onCreateDialog() de la misma clase, a los métodos "setMessage" y "setTittle" les paso como parametros estas propiedades.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(this.mensajeDialogo)
            .setTitle(this.tituloDialogo)
```

En la actividad principal, creo una instancia del dialogo y llamo a los metodos "set" de los 2 atributos que cree.

```
     EjemploDialogo dialogo=new EjemploDialogo();
     dialogo.setTitulo("Titulo");
     dialogo.setMensaje("ejempo mensaje");
```

Finalmente, muestro el dialogo:

```
     dialogo.show(getFragmentManager(),"ejemplo dialogo");
```

Eso es todo, saludos !